# Resetting sequential scan position for repeated SPI calls

Tags: postgresql, cursor

I'm using SPI Postgres cursor to fetch data. It looks like this:

```
 SPI_connect();
 snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), "SELECT * FROM %s;", dataTableName);
 cursorPlan = SPI_prepare(sql, 0, NULL);
 cursorPortal = SPI_cursor_open(NULL, cursorPlan, NULL, NULL, 1);
 SPI_cursor_fetch(cursorPortal, direction, CURSOR_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Before fetching I execute

```
select * from coords4_1 limit 5;
```

and get

```
         x         |         y
-------------------+-------------------
 -138.272695243359 | -185.774616431445
 -170.132300350815 |  35.1918349042535
  148.739065974951 |  213.159712031484
   105.91473756358 | -375.821752008051
  418.450653553009 | -69.8341866955161
```

Then I start fetching. Table is big so I interrupt fetching by some reasons.

I execute

```
select * from coords4_1 limit 5;
```

again and get

```
231.340305414051 -443.616589065641
65.2282955124974 412.122126668692
434.384567663074  63.0593989044428
-19.7921730577946 -223.832104355097
-122.094649355859 467.992015648633
```

This query returns the same result in psql and in program call. It is necessary to restart server to get the first result again.

It seems that table cursor stoped on some place in table. I know there are no guarantees on SELECT query result sequence. Is it possible to reinitialize table cursor without restarting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select * from coords4_1 limit 5;

There's no `ORDER BY` clause here, so you're telling the server "give me whatever five results you feel like".

For reasons of implementation detail, PostgreSQL usually returns the table contents roughly in order. This is because of the synchronized scans code. This isn't guaranteed and any code that relies on it is utterly broken.

Add an `ORDER BY` clause, or [use a *real* cursor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) if you want cursor-like behavior.